# Using ColdFusion Loops to change database query filter

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I have a table with Amounts, and Created Dates.  I want to create a query that loops - AND changes the date within the query. Otherwise I have to do it manually.

Current query:

```
<cfquery name=qWeekly datasource="#DSN#">
    SELECT  SUM(Amount)
    FROM    Transactions
    WHERE ( CreatedDate BETWEEN '1-19-2014' AND '1-25-2014' ) 
    AND   ( Amount > 0 )
</cfquery>
```

I would manually change the filter to `... (CreatedDate BETWEEN '1-19-22014' AND '1-25-2014')...`, then manually change it again to: `(CreatedDate ...BETWEEN '1-26-2014' AND '2-8-2014')`.

What I want to do is something like `Between 'X'  AND 'X+7'`, so that I get one weeks worth of data, incremented by 7 days, so I can generate an output by weekly date ranges. In psuedo code, something like this:

```
<cfif CreatedDate < Now()>
    <cfloop index="x" step="7">
        <cfquery name=qWeekly datasource="#DSN#">
            SELECT  SUM(Amount)
            FROM    Transactions
            WHERE ( CreatedDate BETWEEN 'x' AND 'x+7' ) 
            AND   ( Amount > 0 )
        </cfquery>
    </cfloop>
</cfif>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not mention your dbms (always good to include it with sql questions) but it is possible you could achieve the goal without looping. For example, in SQL Server, you could use a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) to generate a table of week start dates. Then JOIN it back to your Transactions table and aggregate the amounts by week.

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a0ccd/1/0)**

```
<!--- Example: generate a range of 7 weeks --->
<cfset firstSunday = createDate(2014,1,19)>
<cfset lastSunday = dateAdd("ww", 7, firstSunday)
...

<!--- Calculate totals for all weeks in range --->
<cfquery name="getTotalsByWeek" ...>
;WITH ranges ( WeekStartDate ) AS (
     SELECT  <cfqueryparam value="#firstSunday#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date"> AS WeekStartDate
     UNION ALL           
     SELECT  DATEADD(d, 7, WeekStartDate)
     FROM    ranges
     WHERE   <cfqueryparam value="#lastSunday#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">  > WeekStartDate
)
SELECT r.WeekStartDate, SUM(t.Amount) AS TotalAmount
FROM  ranges r  LEFT JOIN Transactions t 
            <!--- CreatedDate falls within 7 days of the start date --->
            ON t.CreatedDate >= r.WeekStartDate 
            AND t.CreatedDate < DATEADD(d, 8, r.WeekStartDate) 
GROUP BY r.WeekStartDate
ORDER BY r.WeekStartDate
</cfquery>
```

**Results:**

```
2014-01-19 00:00:00.000 | 1915.74
2014-01-26 00:00:00.000 | 567.00
2014-02-02 00:00:00.000 | 1250.00
2014-02-09 00:00:00.000 | NULL
2014-02-16 00:00:00.000 | 300.00
2014-02-23 00:00:00.000 | NULL
2014-03-02 00:00:00.000 | NULL
2014-03-09 00:00:00.000 | NULL
```

**NB:** The query above uses a special construct for date comparisons that will work regardless of whether your CreatedDate column contains a date (only) or a date AND time.

```
   col >= startDateAtMidnight AND
   col < dayAfterEndDateAtMidnight
```

Comment: excellent, especially since i forgot a parameter in my original query.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<Cfset datePlaceholder= now()/>


<!--- this would loop for 12 weeks --->
<Cfloop from="7*12" to="1" step="-7" index="stepper">
<cfquery...>
   SELECT SUM(Amount) 
   FROM   Transactions 
   WHERE  (CreatedDate 
              BETWEEN #dateformat(datePlaceholder,'MM-DD-YYYY')#
              AND #dateformat(dateAdd('d',stepper,datePlaceholder),'MM-DD-YYYY')#)
   AND (Amount > 0) 
</cfquery>

...do whatever you need to with this week of data
</cfloop>
```

Cavaets - some types of date fields include time (smalldatetime for example) so you might need to append 00:00:00 or 23:59:59 to them.

You will have to debug this code - I did not run it.

Cfquery is one of those spots were I prefer the tag for readibility (and cutting and pasting from query analyzer or navicat or whatever).

Comment: im comparing the two solutions - the one above, and this does seem cleaner - more CF than SQL.  THank you

Comment: @AaronBirnbaum - SQL is actually the better tool for this task ;-) Querying within a loop is notoriously inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something similar to Mark's, but with parameterized values.

```
 <Cfset datePlaceholder= now()/>


 <!--- this would loop for 12 weeks --->
<Cfloop from="7*12" to="1" step="-7" index="stepper">
   <cfquery...>
      DECLARE @datePlaceholder date = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_date"  value="#datePlaceholder#">
      DECLARE @stepper tinyint = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_tinyint" value="#stepper#">

      SELECT SUM(Amount) 
      FROM   Transactions 
      WHERE  CreatedDate BETWEEN @placeholder AND DateAdd(d, @stepper, @placeholder)
      AND (Amount > 0) 
  </cfquery>

   ...do whatever you need to with this week of data
</cfloop>
```

Note that the DateAdd function in SQL is a little different than DateAdd in ColdFusion